# Java multithreading: how to notify() a single thread after all threads are ready

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm writing a game where a `Player` can be either local or remote, so I have to read the "move" made by him using multithreading.

I have a `PlayerLoop` thread which initially calls `start()` on several `Player` threads. After that, `PlayerLoop` should repeatedly wake up a single `Player` (going from the first to the last one) in a cyclic manner, until the game ends.

However, not always the `Player` will wake up: sometimes `PlayerLoop` notifies the correct `Player`, but it does that too early (the `Player` isn't yet "waiting his turn").

Specifically, when I start the `PlayerLoop` for the first time it seems to work OK, but if during the game I cancel the match and start a new one, then every `Player` just waits their turn forever.

Here's the `PlayerLoop`:

```
public class PlayerLoop extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + "] is alive.");
        this.startPlayers(); // cycles Players and calls .start()
        while (true) {
            Player current = this.getCurrentPlayer();

            current.connect(); // connect to this Player
            synchronized (current) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Notifying Thread [" + current.getName()
                        + "] that it's his turn.");
                    current.notify(); // the player thread "resumes" to eventually produce a "move"
                    current.wait(); // wait for the "move" to be ready
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // The game loop is interrupted, terminate thread
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.applyMove(current.getMove()); // use the "move"
            current.disconnect(); // disconnect this Player

            this.goToNextPlayer();
        }
        System.out.println("Terminating players...");
        this.stopPlayers(); // cycles Players and calls .interrupt()
        System.out.println("Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + "] is dead.");
    }
```

For the moment I'm not testing the "remote" part so here's just the `LocalPlayer` class, which extends `Player`, which extends `Thread`:

```
public class LocalPlayer extends Player {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + "] is alive.");
        while (true) {
            // Wait my turn
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Thread ["
                            + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                            + "] is waiting its turn.");
                    this.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // We are stopping all the players, so terminate thread
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Thread ["
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "] has come to its turn.");
            }
            // Wait for mainLoop to produce a Move
            synchronized (__SomeGameLoop__) {
                System.out.println("Thread ["
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "] is waiting a move.");
                try {
                    __SomeGameLoop__.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // PlayerLoop was interrupted, and he is now interrupting me, so terminate thread
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Thread ["
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                        + "] has been notified of a move.");
            }

            // Get produced move
            this.move = __SomeGameLoop__.getMove();

            // Signal monitor
            synchronized (this) {
                // Notify that I have read the move and that I can communicate it
                this.notify();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thread [" + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + "] is dead.");
    }
}
```

The code above is probably not precise and oversimplified, but here's an excerpt of the game's output:

```
Creating threads...
Thread [PlayerLoop] is alive.
Thread [Player 1] is alive.
Thread [Player 2] is alive.
Thread [Player 2] is waiting its turn.
Thread [Player 1] is waiting its turn.
Notifying Thread [Player 1] that it's his turn.
Thread [Player 1] has come to its turn.
Thread [Player 1] is waiting a move.
GameLoop notifies that a move has been done.
Thread [Player 1] has been notified of a move.
Notify that I have read that move and I can communicate it
Thread [Player 1] is waiting its turn.
Notifying Thread [Player 2] that it's his turn.
Thread [Player 2] has come to its turn.
Thread [Player 2] is waiting a move.
GameLoop notifies that a move has been done.
Thread [Player 2] has been notified of a move.
Notify that I have read that move and I can communicate it
Thread [Player 2] is waiting its turn.
Notifying Thread [Player 1] that it's his turn.
Thread [Player 1] has come to its turn.
Thread [Player 1] is waiting a move.
GameLoop notifies that a move has been done.
Thread [Player 1] has been notified of a move.
Notify that I have read that move and I can communicate it
Thread [Player 1] is waiting its turn.
Notifying Thread [Player 2] that it's his turn.
Thread [Player 2] has come to its turn.
Thread [Player 2] is waiting a move.
Terminating players...
Thread [PlayerLoop] is dead.
PlayerLoop was interrupted, and he is now interrupting me, so terminate thread [Player 2]
We are stopping all the players, so terminate thread [Player 1]
Thread [Player 1] is dead.
Thread [Player 2] is dead.

Creating threads...
Thread [PlayerLoop] is alive.
Thread [Player 1] is alive.
Notifying Thread [Player 1] that it's his turn.
Thread [Player 1] is waiting its turn.
Thread [Player 2] is alive.
Thread [Player 2] is waiting its turn.
....(and here it hangs indefinitely)....
```

The second time threads are created, `PlayerLoop` notifies the `Player` too early. How can I make sure to `notify()` a `Player` only after all the `Player`s are `wait()`ing on their respective monitor?

Comment: Don't: simply check the state (before and) after the signals.

Comment: EDIT: Ok now I get it.. You're talking about getState()

Comment: If you have a known number of players and a predetermined order, you do not need to design your application with multi-threading. There is no added benefit and synchronisation, as you discover, is a pain. I suggest rethinking your design!

Comment: @EricTobias: the fact is that I will also have implement the `Player` contract (connect, disconnect, getMove) using network sockets (which kinda require(?) multithreading) so it does make sense to call every `Player` a `Thread`, doesn't it?

Comment: @EricTobias: and even with `LocalPlayer` to get the "move" from the user I have to let him play on the game field (which means he will move the mouse around, type in some keys if needed, and eventually he will click, thus sending me the move) and I have to "wait" for this, somehow.

Comment: No you don't, you can use Action or Event driven techniques to pilot your game logic. It is much more user friendly. As for your networking issues, threading != multi-threading. I personally would recommend to decouple your player logic from the logic of how input is received. Maybe you could look into message queues to handle all your events, be it local or remote to drive players.

Answer (score 3):

A player should not wait their turn unless it is not yet their turn. Waiting *for* a condition is *unconditional*. So if you don't need to wait for a condition, don't wait for it. The reason the method that calls `wait` is synchronized is so that you can make absolutely sure you need to wait before you wait.

If there is something to wait for, waiting is always safe. If there is nothing to wait for, there is no reason to wait. Do not wait for something that has already happened, it won't happen.

Comment: Nice answer, but I read in a loop couple of times, but each time, I forget what was the previous line. All I remember on each line is `wait` :)

Comment: +1, the only thing to add is [the documentation of `Object.wait()` itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) as it clearly acknowledges your answer and provides a code example.

Answer (score 1):

Please try [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) from Java Standard API, it 's easy and less confusing.

Object.wait and Object.notify is too low level to use  rightly.